# Telnet with php. Control remote APC PDU

Tags: php, telnet, apc

I'm trying to control remote power switch by executing some php commands.

There is a telnet library which I'm using to make a telnet connection: http://www.soucy.org/project/cisco/source.php

My connect function looks like this:

```
public function connect() 
{
    $this->_connection = fsockopen($this->_hostname, $this->_port, $errno, $errstr, $this->_timeout);
    if ($this->_connection === false) {
        die("Error: Connection Failed for $this->_hostname\n");
    } // if
    stream_set_timeout($this->_connection, $this->_timeout);
    $this->_readTo(':');
    if (substr($this->_data, -9) == 'Username:') {
        $this->_send($this->_username);
        $this->_readTo(':');
    } // if
    $this->_send($this->_password);

    $this->_send(''); //blank space, because we need to press <Enter> for the second login prompt 

   //Login Second time

    $this->_send($this->_username2);
    $this->_send($this->_password2);
}
```

Send function looks like this:

```
private function _send($command) 
{
    fputs($this->_connection, $command . "\r\n");
}
```

So if we want to control remote power switch, there is a menu for this. In this menu user can navigate like this:

------- Control Console -------------------------------------------------------

```
 1- Device Manager
 2- Network
 3- System
 4- Logout

 <ESC>- Main Menu, <ENTER>- Refresh
```

> 

When we press 1, we will go to another meniu:

------- Device Manager --------------------------------------------------------

```
 1- Bank Monitor
 2- Outlet Management
 3- Power Supply Status

 <ESC>- Back, <ENTER>- Refresh
```

> 

and so on... So we can access the outlet which we want by just typing these numbers.

Function to reload the outlet (outlet number 22):

```
public function ReloadOutlet22() 
{

$this->_send('1'); // Access Device Manager
$this->_send('2'); // Access Outlet Management
$this->_send('1'); // Outlet Control/Configuration
$this->_send();    // '<Enter> to continue'
$this->_send('22'); // Access Outlet number 22
$this->_send('6');  // Delayed Reboot (reboot with 5 sec delay)
$this->_send('YES'); // 'Yes' to continue
$this->_send();      // <Enter> to continue'

//Everything is working till there. I can successfully reload the outlet which I want. After the reload I want to go to the main menu and logout from this console.

$this->_send('\e');  // <Esc> - back
$this->_send('\e');  // <Esc> - back
$this->_send('\e');  // <Esc> - back
$this->_send('\e');  // <Esc> - back
$this->_send('\e');  // <Esc> - back
$this->_send('4');   // Logout
}
```

So there is a problem. Next time , when I want to reload another outlet, for example outlet with a number 23, I can't successfully login to the APC PDU. I can see at the login prompt that there was a try to use '\e' as a Username and as a password.

So maybe guys you have an idea, why after successful reload my code doesn't work as it should? Why I can't go back to the main menu and logout?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: are you sure you need 5 esc sequences to get back?
what happens when you simply disconnect and reconnect?

Comment: If I just simply disconnect and reconnect, I will be still logged in. If I want to reload different power outlets, It would be more simple to achieve if I could just logout. Otherwise my "reboot outlet" sequence won't work. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: your problem descriptions sounds like you send more esc sequences than necessery, maybe you need to parse the screens on your way back?

Comment: If I want to enter the main menu where I could use "Logout" command by pressing number 4, I would need to use 5 escape sequences.

But it looks like the script sometimes just stops after the 'YES' command is sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APC provides both the Control Console (text-based menu driven), and also their Command Line Interface ("CLI") which accepts a variety of command lines specific to controlling the PDU's outlets.

To use the Command Line Interface instead of the Control Console, append " -c" to your password when logging in with telnet--i.e., if your telnet password is "abcdefg", then login with password "abcdefg -c" to enter the CLI.  The CLI command prompt is "APC>".

The CLI command to power cycle (reboot) an outlet is simply :

```
APC> reboot x
(x = the outlet number to power cycle)
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably need double quotes around "\e" - single quotes treat it as a literal string (no escape sequences like \n)

```
$this->_send("\e");  // <Esc> - back
```

If that doesn't work use

```
$this->_send(chr(27));  // <Esc> - back
```

to send the escape key using the numeric ASCII value

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

Comment: I don't know why, but session hangs somehow, and I can't login normally when I try to reload another outlet. 

Thank you for escape key sequence, I will use it!

Comment: When SSHing into a server, you might need to sleep for a second or two after sending the password for the login scripts to run (and hard drives to spin up) before sending any commands.   The server will throw away any input between when you send the password and when you actually see the login prompt.   sleeping for 2-3 seconds fixed this problem for me.

Comment: Yes dear Robert, I tried to use it, but if I use for example sleep(3); command on my php code I will get these errors:

Severity: Notice

Message: fputs(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

Comment: Maybe you need to read everything that the server has sent before you login the second time (to clear the buffers)

Comment: Also your send command appends \r\n so you are really pressing <escape> <enter> and hitting enter after every number. Probably not what you want

Comment: Yes you are correct. When I use <escape> there is no need to press <enter> , but I need to press <enter> when I want to send a number to choose a different menu. How is it possible to clear the buffers? Or this is done everytime when I use function _readTo($char) ? Should I use this function after every sent command?

thank you for your time Robert!